# Summarize the DeviceCode based on users in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data

```
ID   User1   User2   DeviceCode
1    John             D1
2             John    D2
3    Brian            D3
4    Brian            D4
5    Davis            D5
6             Davis   D5
```

For the above kind of table Layout in MySQL I am trying to figure out count of how many different DeviceCode each user is mapped to

Looking forward to the guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(user1, user2) as user, count(distinct devicecode)
from t
group by user;
```

It seems odd to me that only one user column is populated per row.  Why bother having two columns in that case?